# ini_set not working in the same script

Tags: php, prestashop

I am using a prestashop and I need to change the max_input_vars so translation changes are applied from the Translation section.

I cannot use php_value in .htaccess because of my hosting provider policy, so I need to use the php.ini file.
I've created it into the prestashop administration folder with the content:

max_input_vars = 3000

But when I update the translations, I get the error of max_input_vars, so it is not being changed with the php.ini. I've also tried without blanks, with a trailing ";" and no effect.

To check it, I've created a file with just phpinfo() and it tells me that it is set to 1000 (the default value).
I supposed that using ini_set just above the phpinfo call would change its value (only for that script), but in fact, it does not change anything.
So, I put:

```
ini_set("max_input_vars","3000");
phpinfo();
```

and the value I am getting for max_input_vars is 1000.

Any idea on how to change the value, or why it is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This configuration setting is not settable at runtime from code. If you look at the [list of configuration settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) you will see that its "changeable" value is `PHP_INI_PERDIR`. [This page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) explains what that means.

`ini_set` can only affect settings that are marked changeable as `PHP_INI_USER`.

The logical explanation for this is that the setting affects PHP's behavior *before* your code has had a chance to run.

Answer (score 2):

The setting applies while PHP is trying to parse the data sent to the script. This happens *before* your script is even executed. So you simply cannot set it at runtime because the setting affects something pre-runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Everything is clear now. So, the only way of changing it is setting the directive in php.ini, isn't it?

Comment: Well, I've got another error but I'll open a new thread because it has to do with prestashop and it is a bit strange. Thank you to all of you!